# how to stop runaway flashing NSButton / NSTimer (IOS or OSX ok)

Tags: macos, nstimer, nsbutton

I'm trying to make an NSButton (but I could use the technique for iOS too, so any answers are welcome).

I have a button where hiding/enabling is turned on and off:

```
-(void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    timerStatus = 0;
    timerTest = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                           target:self
                         selector:@selector(changeButtonState:)
                         userInfo:nil
                          repeats:YES]; 
}

-(void) changeButtonState:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    if (timerStatus == 2) return;
    if (timerStatus == 0) {
        timerStatus = 1;
        saveButton.enabled = YES;
        saveButton.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        timerStatus = 0;
        saveButton.enabled = NO;
        saveButton.hidden = YES;
    }

}
```

The button blinks ok, but after it's associated method is fired (in this case a save action), I want the timer to stop and the button to stop blinking. It's this last part that's giving me a headache.. Any help appreciated.

```
    - (IBAction)saveItemNotes:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);     
    <do my save stuff here>
    timerStatus = 2;
    [timerTest invalidate];
    timerTest = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just invalidate your timer in that same method where you change the button state.

Better yet, don't do it this way. 
Use Core Animation instead if you want to draw attention to an interface item.

Comment: Thanks. can you point me to an appropriate Core Animation sample/example/tutorial.. I was thinking as I did this, that there must be a better way..